# My program is not giving the desired output for Exponential / inverse log transformation

Tags: c++, opencv

I implemented it by first constructing look up table and then calling it in the transformation function. Here is my code for the Exponential Transformation (inverse log transformation)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

//Construct LookUpTable
const int BASE = 1.02;
vector<uchar> getInvLogLUT(uchar maxValue){
    double C = 255.0 / (pow(BASE, maxValue) -1);
    vector<uchar> LUT(256, 0);
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        LUT[i] = (int) round(C * (pow(BASE, i) - 1));
    return LUT;

}
//Transformation Function
void processImage(Mat& I){
    double maxValue;
    minMaxLoc(I, NULL, &maxValue);
    vector<uchar> LUT = getInvLogLUT((uchar) maxValue);
    for(int i = 0; i < I.rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < I.cols; j++){
            I.at<uchar>(i, j) = LUT[I.at<uchar>(i, j)];
        }
    }
}


int main(){
    Mat image = imread("invlog.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat process_image = image.clone();


    processImage(process_image);

    imshow("Original", image);
    imshow("Processed", process_image);


    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What behavior do you get? What behavior did you expect instead? You can also post the images to help others finding the issue in your code (but you still need to answer the first two questions).

Comment: OpenCV has a built-in `LUT()` function, by the way.

Comment: Both parameters to `pow()` should be `double`.

Comment: `LUT[i] = (int) round(...)` seems unlikely when `LUT` is vector of `uchar`.

Comment: `int BASE = 1.02` will result in a base of 1.